# Why is my Palindrome code running true for every scenario?

Tags: javascript

This code returns true for every scenario; it returns true if it's a palindrome and it returns true if it's not a palindrome.

```
 function isPalindrome(string){
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  var charactersArr = string.split(' ');
  var validCharacters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split(' ');

  var lettersArr = [];
  charactersArr.forEach(char => {
    if (validCharacters.indexOf(char)> - 1) lettersArr.push(char);
  });
  return lettersArr.join(' ') === lettersArr.reverse().join(' ');
}
isPalindrome("Taco Cat");
```

Comment: You need to split your strings on `''` not `' '` to get an array of characters.  Do this and the logic works.

Comment: I don't think `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split(' ')` does what you think it does.

Comment: You're splitting on spaces

Answer (score 0):

```
function palindrome(str) {
 var re = /[^A-Za-z0-9]/g;
 str = str.toLowerCase().replace(re, '');
 var len = str.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < len/2; i++) {
   if (str[i] !== str[len - 1 - i]) {
       return false;
   }
 }
 return true;
}
```

Use this code for checking palindromes . You are complicating your code by passing in  `var validCharacters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split(' ');`
You could use `re` like I have to include all possible combinations including numbers !

Answer (score 0):

It always returns `true` because `lettersArr` is always empty. Try to debug your code using debugger or just use `console.log` for this purpose.

I believe at least this line `var charactersArr = string.split(' ');` is not doing what is expected: it splits a sentence by space characters into words instead of splitting into separate letters.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `lettersArr`is always empty .... Try this code:

```js
function isPalindrome(string) {
  let reversed = string.toLowerCase().split('').reverse().join('');
  return reversed === string.toLowerCase()
}

let result1 = isPalindrome("Foo bar")
let result2 = isPalindrome("mom")

console.log(result1, result2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`lettersArr` is not what you expect.

You are splitting the input string by spaces, which means you get `['taco', 'cat']` and not `['t', 'a', 'c', 'o', 'c', 'a', 't']`.

Then when this line runs:

```
if (validCharacters.indexOf(char)> - 1) lettersArr.push(char);
```

`char` is `'taco'` which isn't found in `validCharacters`, so nothing gets pushed into `lettersArr`.

And since `lettersArr` is empty:

```
lettersArr.join(' ') === lettersArr.reverse().join(' ');
```

Becomes:

```
[].join(' ') === [].reverse().join(' ')
```

Which, of course, it always true.

---

To fix it you simply want to split the string by an empty string, which gives you array of single character strings.

```js
 function isPalindrome(string){
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  var charactersArr = string.split('');
  var validCharacters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');

  var lettersArr = [];
  charactersArr.forEach(char => {
    if (validCharacters.indexOf(char)> - 1) lettersArr.push(char);
  });
  return lettersArr.join(' ') === lettersArr.reverse().join(' ');
}

console.log("Taco Cat", isPalindrome("Taco Cat"));
console.log("abc", isPalindrome("abc"));
```